# Merge Data of cosmos Db Collections

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

How can I merge two collections of data into one collection? Let us assume the two collections Candidates and CandidateSkills. Now I want to add candidate skills as an array in Candidates table.

```
ex: 
{ 
  "Id" : "xyz", "CandidateName":"Test", "CandidateSkilles": ["Angular", 
  "Azure"] 
}
{ 
 "Id" : "xyz", "CandidateName":"Test", "CandidateSkilles": [".net", "Azure"] 
}
```

How can this operation be done in an automated way in Azure pipeline or one-time script execution?

Comment: What do you mean `skills as an array`? An array of every document in Candidates table?Or just an array which contains all the data of Skills?

Comment: List of skills as a property in Candidate Collection

ex: {
"Id"" : "xyz",
"CandidateName":"Test",
"CandidateSkilles": ["Angular", "Azure"]
}

Comment: So,every `CandidateName` has same `Skills` array?

Comment: Skills are different for every candidate and that information is available in CandidateSkills

Comment: There's no specific way to do this; you'd have to create some type of custom transform yourself, especially since you're modifying the schema (embedding documents from one collection into documents into another, transformed into arrays). Also FYI this is unrelated to Azure DevOps (so I removed the tag accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

Since `Skills` are different for every candidate,so it seems that there is no direct way to merge the data one on one.

If there is a connector column(like same `ID`),i would suggest you using JOIN in the sql and produce the merge data like you mentioned in your question:

```
{ 
  "Id" : "xyz", "CandidateName":"Test", "CandidateSkilles": ["Angular", 
  "Azure"] 
}
{ 
 "Id" : "xyz", "CandidateName":"Test", "CandidateSkilles": [".net", "Azure"] 
}
```

Then use [bulk insert library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/bulk-executor-overview) to import the data into a totally new collection.